# Symfony3 FOSUserBundle configuration

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to config Symfony3 with FOSUserBundle, followed Symfony [FOSUserBundle Docs][1] step by step but at the end I get this error:

```
ParameterNotFoundException in RegisterMappingsPass.php line 237:
You have requested a non-existent parameter "Could not determine the Doctrine manager. Either Doctrine is not configured or a bundle is misconfigured.".
in RegisterMappingsPass.php line 237
at RegisterMappingsPass->getManagerName(object(ContainerBuilder)) in RegisterMappingsPass.php line 183
at RegisterMappingsPass->getChainDriverServiceName(object(ContainerBuilder)) in RegisterMappingsPass.php line 151
at RegisterMappingsPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in Compiler.php line 104
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in ContainerBuilder.php line 545
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in Kernel.php line 477
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->boot() in Kernel.php line 166
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 30
at require('~/Dev/test-api/web/app_dev.php') in router_dev.php line 40
```

I checked my vendor directory and doctrine exists.

my security.yml:

```
    # To get started with security, check out the documentation:
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
    security:
        encoders:
            FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
    
        role_hierarchy:
            ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
            ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    
        providers:
            fos_userbundle:
                id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    
        firewalls:
            main:
                pattern: ^/
                form_login:
                    provider: fos_userbundle
                    csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                    # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                    # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
    
                logout:       true
                anonymous:    true
    
        access_control:
            - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

config.yml:



imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: "@CambioBundle/Resources/config/services.xml" }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
#    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
      default_connection: db_query
      connections:
        db_query:
            driver:   %database_driver%
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
            # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
            #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
            #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
            #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
            #   3. Uncomment next line:
            #     path:     "%database_path%"

#    orm:
#        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
#        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
#        auto_mapping: true

##FOSUserBundle Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Cambio\CambioBundle\Entity\User

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

Really cant see what am doing wrong here.

Update:

composer.jason:

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev"


  [1]: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html
```

Comment: What branch of FOSUserBundle are you using? Only the master is compliant with Symfony3 atm

Comment: yep thats the one am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not related with your FOSUserBundle, it is related with wrong doctrine configuration. you should uncomment orm section of doctrine settings in config.yml

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
```

Comment: @Tomazi And? The same problem? Did you clear the cache?

Comment: well this actually worked, was nto mentioned in the Docs but thank you for your help much appricated